# Prove quadrilateral ABCD is a parallelogram

Tags: quadrilateral

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9b7p.png)

In the image, EFGH is a parallelogram, and BE=HC=GD=AF.
Can I prove that ABCD is also a parallelogram?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question should be reversed.

You are given $ABCD$ parallelogram and points $E,F,G,H$ are distributed on the sides with equal distance.

We can use the vectorial characterisation of a parallelogram $\vec{AD}=\vec{BC}$.

Then with Chasles additive relations:

$\vec{FG}=\underbrace{\vec{FA}}_{=\vec{CH}}+\underbrace{\vec{AD}}_{=\vec{BC}}+\underbrace{\vec{DG}}_{=\vec{EB}}=\vec{EB}+\vec{BC}+\vec{CH}=\vec{EH}$

So $EHGF$ is a parallelogram too.

- We can say $\vec{FA}=\vec{CH}$ because $(AD)//(BC)$ and $F\in(AB)$ and $H\in(BC)$ and $AF=CH$ in distance.

Similar reason for $\vec{DG}=\vec{EB}$.

Comment: My approach is as below:
BA = BE+EF+FA
     =BH+HE+HG+FA
     =BC+CB+BH+GF+HG+FA
     =CH+HG+GA+BC
     =CH+HG+GA+AD+DA+BC
     =CH+HG+GD+DA+BC
     =CD+DA+BC
This is the furthest I can go as I cannot prove AD=BC

Comment: You are making more complicated than it is. Just replace each of my  " ? " in the hint by a single term. For instance $\vec{FA}=\vec{CH}$ because parallel and same length (see your hypothesis AF=HC). Can you guess the other two ?

Comment: In my question AF=HC, they are not vector, if I was misleading I apologize.
It means they have same length only

Comment: Hmm, you are right, I'm confused too now! Are you sure the question is not reversed ? You were given $ABCD$ parallelogram and have to prove $EHGF$ is one too ? Else we seem to miss details about how to construct the points A,B,C and D.

Comment: I'm not sure, I was asked with only this picture and that's all I know.

Comment: Ok, I 've redacted my answer assuming this hypothesis...